# ionic app works only on wifi but not on cellular connection

Tags: ionic-framework, wifi

My ionic app works fine on the emulator and on my device (using wifi)
But as soon as I switch over to cellular connection I get an

**Application Error**

**net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (http://192.168.0.13:8100/)**

Why can I not use the app with cellular connection?

Comment: what command did u used to build apk..?

Comment: this one **ionic run android -l -c -s**

Comment: this makes..apk..in debug mode(live reload)..which will run only in that..wifi environment..!! use : ionic run android

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic run android -l -c -s
```

-l : livereload, it compiles hybrid app itself, watching for any changes to its files and reloading the app when needed.as soon as u make any changes in code,it will reflect in app on device.

-c : an app’s console logs can be printed to the terminal/command prompt

-s : the development server’s request logs can be printed.

this will help u only in that network and until u stop your command.

[read here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html)

```
ionic run android
```

this command will make apk to run in any environment.

Comment: Thanks this really helped :)